# Regex logic for parsing date in a custom format not working?

Tags: python, regex, generator, yield

**Problem:**
Iam parsing a logline from a service which i installed with a custom date field.So i want to match the log line and then see if new logs came into the logfile.

But to match the logfile iam using the regex to exact match the date in the logline.I attached the code part below.

**Code:**

```
 def matchDate(self , line):
                matchThis = ""
                #Thu Jul 27 00:03:27 2017
                matched = re.match(r'\d\d\d\ \d\d\d \d\d\ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d\d\d\d',line)
                print matched
                if matched:
                #matches a date and adds it to matchThis
                        matchThis = matched.group()
                        print 'Match found {}'.format(matchThis)
                else:
                        matchThis = "NONE"
                return matchThis

        def log_parse(self):
                currentDict = {}
                with open(self.default_log , 'r') as f:
                        for line in f:
                                print line
                                if line.startswith(self.matchDate(line) , 0 ,24 ):
                                        if currentDict:
                                                yield currentDict
                                        currentDict = {
                                               "date" : line.split('[')[0][:24],
                                               "no"   : line.split(']')[0][-4:-1],
                                               "type" : line.split(':')[0][-4:-1],
                                               "text" : line.split(':')[1][1:]
                                              }
                                else:
                                        pass
#                                       currentDict['text'] += line
                        yield currentDict
```

Here it is not matching anything so i fixed this by new regex like this

```
'[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}'
```

Here is the regex editor [http://regexr.com/3gl67]

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem and to exact match the logline.

Example Logline:

```
Wed Aug 30 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.
Wed Aug  2 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.
```

[image]

Comment: `r'\w{3,4} \w{3,4} \d+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}'` Is this what you need?

Comment: `Wed Aug 2 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.` is not matching

Comment: Actually it is not `Wed Aug 2 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.` but `Wed Aug  2 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.` with extra space after AUG

Comment: I cannot find the extra space you are talking about... but I think this one will be fine. `r'\w{3,4}\s+\w{3,4}\s+\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d{4}'`

Comment: http://regexr.com/3gl6j check this once

Comment: I have checked the new regex, it works fine. Repeat it `r'\w{3,4}\s+\w{3,4}\s+\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\d{4}'`

Answer (score 0):

I developed this code which might help you to detect the desired pattern:

```
import re

#detecting Thu Jul 27 00:03:27 2017

line = 'Wed Aug 30 13:05:47 2017 [3163] INFO: Something new, the something you looking for is hidden. Update finished.'

days = '(?:Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri) '
months = '(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec) '
day_number = '\d{2} '
time = '\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} '
year = '\d{4} '
date = days+months+day_number

pattern = date + time + year

date_matched = re.findall(date, line)
time_matched = re.findall(time, line)
year_matched = re.findall(year, line)
full_matched = re.findall(pattern, line)
print(date_matched, year_matched, time_matched , full_matched)

if len(full_matched) > 0:
  print('yes')
else:
  print('no')
```

I used specific patterns for months, days, year and time. I am not much familiar with `re.match` function so I used `re.findall`. My priority was simplicity and clearness of the code, so I guess more efficient code or patterns are available. I really hope this one could come in handy anyway.

Good luck